# Some problems with the !kick command code

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm having some problem with my `Discord.js` kick command.

My code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const { prefix, token } = require('../config.json');

module.exports = {
 name: 'kick',
 description: 'kick users',
 execute(message, args) {
  if (!message.member.hasPermission('KICK_MEMBERS')) {
   return message.channel.send({
    embed: {
     color: 16777201,
     description: `:x: | ${message.author}, You are not allowed to use this command.`,
     footer: {
      text: ` | Required permission: KICK_MEMBERS`,
     },
    },
   });
  }
  if (!message.guild.me.permissions.has('KICK_MEMBERS')) {
   return message.channel.send({
    embed: {
     color: 16777201,
     description: `:x: | ${message.author}, I am not allowed to use this command.`,
     footer: {
      text: ` | Required permission: KICK_MEMBERS`,
     },
    },
   });
  }

  if (!args[0]) {
   return message.channel.send({
    embed: {
     color: 16777201,
     description: `:x: | ${message.author}, You need to mention a user first.`,
     footer: {
      text: ` | Example: !kick @Bot`,
     },
    },
   });
  }
  const member =
   message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]);
  if (member.user.id === message.author.id) {
   return message.channel.send({
    embed: {
     color: 16777201,
     description: `:x: | ${message.author}, You cannot expel yourself.`,
     footer: {
      text: ` | Example: !kick @Bot`,
     },
    },
   });
  }
  try {
   member.kick();
   message.channel.send(`${member} has been kicked!`);
  } catch (e) {
   return message.channel.send(`User isn't in this server!`);
  }
 },
};
```

Ignore the code not being complete, I'm still thinking about the design of the embeds!

I'm trying to do 3 things:

- I would like if someone tried to use the command by mentioning the bot, they would say something like "you are not allowed to do this"
- The other thing I want is that it is not possible for a user to kick someone above him
- I want the member to be kicked you have to react with yes or no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I'm going to try to solve your problems one by one:

---

> - First of all, I would like if someone tried to use the command by mentioning the bot, they would say something like "you are not allowed to do this"

You can execute an `if` statement to detect if the member mentioned shares the same `ID` as your bot using the [`client.user`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=user) property (the user your client is logged in as)

```js
if (member.id === client.user.id)
 return message.channel.send('You cannot ban me');
```

---

> - The other thing I want is that it is not possible for a user to kick someone above him

You can solve this by comparing the [`roles.highest.position`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role?scrollTo=position) property of both members. This property will return a number. the higher the number, the higher the role in priority.

```js
if (message.member.roles.highest.position <= member.roles.highest.position)
 return message.channel.send(
  'Cannot kick that member because they have roles that are higher or equal to you.'
 );
```

---

> - And lastly, I want the member to be kicked you have to react with yes or no

For this you'll need to use a reaction collector. This is how you can do it using [`Message.awaitReactions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=awaitReactions). This method will wait for someone to react to a message, then log the emoji reacted.

```js
// first send the confirmation message, then react to it with yes/no emojis
message.channel
 .send(`Are you sure you want to kick ${member.username}?`)
 .then((msg) => {
  msg.react('');
  msg.react('');

  // filter function
  const filter = (reaction, user) =>
   ['', ''].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id; // make sure it's the correct reaction, and make sure it's the message author who's reacting to it

  message
   .awaitReactions(filter, { time: 30000 }) // make a 30 second time limit before cancelling
   .then((collected) => {
    // do whatever you'd like with the reactions now

    if (message.reaction.name === '') {
     // kick the user
    } else {
     // don't kick the user
    }
   })
   .catch(console.log(`${message.author.username} didn't react in time`));
 });
```

---